# How to use android recipe?

Tags: python, android, apk

How to use android recipe. There is a file on the off github (https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/__init__.py), but I don't know how to attach it to my project. More precisely, how to fit android.runnable into buildozer requirements

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from jnius import autoclass

from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread

WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')
activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity

class Wv(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_webview, 0)

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def create_webview(self, *args):
        webview = WebView(activity)
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)
        wvc = WebViewClient();
        webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);
        activity.setContentView(webview)
        webview.loadUrl('http://www.google.com')

class ServiceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Wv()
if name == 'main': ServiceApp().run()
```